# spring-kafka: autoconfiguration issue using ReplyingKafkaTemplate

Tags: spring-kafka

**Issue**: As a producer, If I wanted to use **ReplyingKafkaTemplate**, 
I would be configuring only **KafkaMessageListenerContainer**
but auto configuration gets failed with below logs

**KafkaConfiguration.java**:

```
        @Autowired
        private KafkaProperties properties;

        @Bean
        public ConsumerFactory<Long, String> cf() {

          return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<> 
             (properties.getConsumer().buildProperties());
        }

        @Bean
        public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> 
          container() {

            ContainerProperties props = new ContainerProperties("replies");
            KafkaMessageListenerContainer<Long, String> container
              = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf(),props);             
            return container;
        }



        @Bean
        public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<Long, String, String> replyingKafkaTemplate(KafkaMessageListenerContainer<Long, String> container ){               
            return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<Long, Order, String>(pf()), container);
        }
```

Below Autoconfiguration in **KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration** causing this issue:

```
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {}
```

Logs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaListenerContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'kafkaListenerContainerFactory' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:767) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:508) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.barath.app.KafkaProducerApplication.main(KafkaProducerApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1646) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1205) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:855) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

**Updated**:

As pointed out in the answer, issue caused due to custom creation of consumer factory. Using of auto configuration has resolved the issue.

**PS**: I can avoid this issue by creating a bean of type ConsumerFactory but just wanted to know whether it can be controlled as part of auto configuration itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show all your configuration (pf, cf etc).

However, you seem to be confusing container and factory.

`KafkaMessageListenerContainer` is not a container factory, it is a container.

That said, I think you are over complicating things - just use Boot's auto configured factory to create the reply container. This works fine for me...

```
public class So53573729Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So53573729Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Long, String> repliesContainer(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, String> containerFactory) {

        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Long, String> repliesContainer = 
                containerFactory.createContainer("replies");
        repliesContainer.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("repliesGroup");
        repliesContainer.setAutoStartup(false);
        return repliesContainer;
    }

    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<Long, String, String> replyingTemplate(
            ProducerFactory<Long, String> pf,
            ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Long, String> repliesContainer) {

        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, repliesContainer);
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I tried as per the documentation [replyingkafka](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_reference.html#replying-template). Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @GaryRussell, thank you for this really cool library. Much like barath I got confused. It would be great if there was a separate example codebase on client running sending request and the server responding on another topic just to make clear what should go where.

Comment: It's always a good idea to look at the framework tests for examples. There is a [test case here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/f5b6927cdb5344c7d5e31c205285e95b09cebd92/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/requestreply/ReplyingKafkaTemplateTests.java#L107-L126) with the corresponding [server side here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/requestreply/ReplyingKafkaTemplateTests.java#L341-L345).